# Do zeros present along the diagonal yield complex eigenvalues?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, soft-question, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I was told today by a friend that having a zero along there main diagonal of a matrix will promote complex eigenvalues. I do not believe this is true because the below matrix **Z** has a zero present along the diagonal and yet has all real eigenvalues.

$Z=\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 2 & 0 & -1\\
1 & 0 & -1 & 0\\
2 & 0 & 0 & -1\\
\end{bmatrix}$

Besides proving this statement incorrect with an empirical example, is there any significance to zeros being along the diagonal of a square matrix with respect to eigenvalues?

Comment: Consider 2-by-2 matrices with zeros along the diagonal. Can you say something about their eigenvalues?

Comment: A symmetric matrix has real eigenvalues and can have zero diagonal.

Answer (score 2):

Your counter example is correct (you could also consider the zero matrix, it has lots of zeros everywhere, but no non-real eigenvalues). Remember that similar matrices have the same eigenvalues. However, zeros here or there in a matrix does not say much about zeros here or there in all matrices similar to it. Thus, you can't expect much from seeing a zero on the main diagonal as far as qualitative information about the linear transformation.

Comment: For example, every matrix of trace zero is similar to one all of whose diagonal entries are zero.